python- os.makedirs(path, exists_ok=True) returning with FileExistsError[WinError 183]
I am executing a file copy operation using python. I am executing os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True) to make sure that the destination folder exists before copying the file, and create the folder if it doesn't exist. I am getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last) :
    File "path\to\script\script.py", line 93, in <module>
        os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
    File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'path\to\file'


Interesting thing is that, I am able to execute this code successfully from my user account, but the error is thrown when it is executed by a service account.
The previous Question-Answers suggest:

use of 'exist_ok' parameter, I am passing exist_ok=True.
A comment suggests to close the open files from the folder and then execute the script. I have checked and confirmed that- no files from the folder are being used. Also, the script is being executed successfully through my user account, but showing the error when executed by the service account. So, I guess the issue should not be about open files.
A comment suggests that 'exist_ok' parameter returns the error if a file with same name(the name of folder you are trying to create) already exists at the location. I have checked and confirmed that- there is no file with same name at the specified location.

I am not sure why this error is being encountered. I expect that the following change should solve the problem-
if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.path.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)

But, I was curious about the reason behind this and also the code-change would add another iteration of testing(which I want to avoid). I would like to know any workaround for the issue.
Thanks,

Please have a look here: https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/os.html#os.mkdir It seems you have either mode issue, aka permission issue, or you are using Python version < 3.4.1. Alternatively, most probably, you have created that directory manually with your user (inheriting all the permissions you have). Thus, remove it and let the script create for your own.

I am using Python 3.12.4, It seems the issue lies with file access permissions to the service account, will try to remove the directory and let the script create it so that it is accessible. Thanks!!
